# Flex Collapsible Panel?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using this collapsible panel - [link](http://hasseg.org/blog/?p=113). Unfortunately, I have a problem using it with application states. I have a state where this panel is visible, when I switch to this state, this panel shows, when I click on it, it opens and its content shows. If I switch to another state (this panel is removed from display), and then switch back to the previous state, the collapsible panel stays open, but its content disappears. In other words, the collapsible panel's content doesn't persist through states.

Anyone know what the problem is? Or is there another collapsible panel that can work around this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this [CollapsiblePanel component by Arc90](http://lab.arc90.com/2008/03/17/collapsiblepanel/) with some success.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this one EnhancedTitleWindow: http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=535